# When does a Yammer user have no home_tabs?

Tags: yammer

Calling `api/v1/users/current.json` on a verified user on Yammer would normally return an array of feeds in JSON format at the path `web_preferences - home_tabs` but I have at least two logins which have no `home_tabs` entry. It's not empty; it's simply not there.

Does anyone know why this might happen? Or how else I might go about fetching that user's feeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of `web_preferences` is undocumented API, so I guess no apps should be depending on it. To fetch a user's groups, see this question: [Yammer API - Can we get list of groups from yammer API for a current user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697996/yammer-api-can-we-get-list-of-groups-from-yammer-api-for-a-current-user)